# Log Sentry events to stdout

Tags: python, logging, sentry

Using the Python Sentry SDK, is it possible to log Sentry events (`capture_message`, `capture_exception`, etc.) to stdout, preferably through the `logging` module? I'm aware of the SDK's logging integration, but as far as I understand, that sends logger messages to Sentry rather than the other way around. The use case for this is testing and debugging.